# IllegalArgumentException in java?

Tags: java

When I try to run my RMI application, it shows me:

```
java.rmi.server.ExportException: remote object implements illegal remote interface; nested exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:illegal remote method encountered : public abstract void DirInterface.addDetails();
```

Server code:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

public class AddServer {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            DirInterface addService = new Dir();
            Naming.rebind("AddService", addService);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
 public class Client {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         try {
              DirInterface st  = (DirInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+args[0]+"/AddService"); 
              st.addDetails();
              String det = st.getDetails();
              System.out.println(det);
              String xx = st.getContact();
              System.out.println(xx);
         } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);
         }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace! Change `System.out.println(e);` to `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0):

It could be beause client and server may not be using the same version of DirInterface.